# aspnetcore and applicationinsights.tracelistener

Tags: asp.net-core, system.diagnostics, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to use application insights trace logging/search when using aspnetcore and/or any .net core app?

I was able to add the applicationinsights.aspnetcore nuget but it doesn't seem that has capabilities for trace logging.

It seems the tracelistener nuget package requires full .net. How are people doing trace logging/search on dotnetcore code?

Answer (score 0):

The Application Insights ASP.NET Core nuget adds the ability to automatically track requests and exceptions in your web app.
However, you can use the Application Insights core telemetry API to send custom telemetry, such as traces or custom events.

See the [core telemetry API documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/) on how to do it - specifically you need to use the TrackTrace method of the TelemetryClient class.

Hope this helps,

Asaf